# General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint - laravel migrations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, migration

I'm trying to add a couple of foreign keys to a pivot table, like thus:-

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('author');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('content');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        });
    }
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        });
    }
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->primary(['post_id', 'tag_id']);
            $table->bigInteger('post_id');
            $table->bigInteger('tag_id');
            // $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
            // $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        });

        Schema::table('post_tag', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
        }); 
        
    }
```

I run the migrations and receive an error like thus:-

```
In Connection.php line 692:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
  : alter table `post_tag` add constraint `post_tag_post_id_foreign` foreign
  key (`post_id`) references `posts` (`id`) on delete cascade)


In Connection.php line 485:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Looking around the net and I'm led to believe its an integrity violation between primary/foreign key datatypes. Like, a foreign key with an integer data type can't reference a primary key whose type is of bigInt. But, in my migration, I'm ensuring the types are the same. Alas, no matter, I still get the error and my migrations fail to compile?

Help

Comment: Sould be unsigned `$table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');` and `$table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_id');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bigIncrements()` method creates an auto-incrementing **UNSIGNED BIGINT** (primary key) equivalent column, so you need to define **unsigned** also for foreign key, because foreign key need to be same type as your primary key :

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_id');

// or

$table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned();
$table->bigInteger('tag_id')->unsigned();
```

Answer (score 1):

`bigIncrements` are big unsigned integer

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

change the `tag_id`, `post_id` field type to unsigned

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_id');
```

As you did with the `user_id` in the posts table.